# NotificationListenerService - service won't stop when stopService() is called

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to implement a service that will listen to the incoming notifications. I've googled some and found `NotificationListenerService`.

The way I want to work with the service is the following:

- user can start/stop the service by interacting with two buttons (Start service, stop service)
- once the service is started it should run in the background until it is explicitly stopped by the user (using the stop service button)
- when the service is started, if the user opens the app I want to let the user interact with the service (as an example, call `cancelAllNotifications()` on a button click)

**Buttons - user interaction with the service**

```
button_start.setOnClickListener {
    logDebug("Button start clicked.")
    startService()
}

//BUG service doesn't seem to stop
button_stop.setOnClickListener {
    logDebug("Button stop clicked.")
    stopService()
}

button_cancel_notif.setOnClickListener {
    logDebug("Button cancel all notifications clicked.")
    cancelAllNotifications()
}
```

I've managed to start the service and bind it to the fragment, but when I call `stopService()`, even though it returns `true`, the service won't stop.

Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest**

```
<service android:name=".services.NLService"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**class NLService**

```
class NLService : NotificationListenerService() {

    private val binder = NLBinder()
    var isBound: Boolean = false

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        logDebug("NLService is bind!")
        isBound = true
        val action = intent?.action
        logDebug("onBind action: $action")

        return if (action == SERVICE_INTERFACE) {
            logDebug("Bound by system")
            super.onBind(intent)
        } else {
            logDebug("Bound by application")
            binder
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)

        logDebug(sbn.toString())
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn)

        logDebug(sbn.toString())
    }

    inner class NLBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService(): NLService = this@NLService
    }
}
```

**ServiceFragment**

```
open class ServiceFragment : Fragment(), INLServiceActions, INLBinderActions {

    private lateinit var notificationListenerIntent: Intent

    private var notificationListenerService: NLService? = null
    private lateinit var binder: NLService.NLBinder

    private val connection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {}

        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            logDebug("onServiceConnected called.")
            binder = service as NLService.NLBinder
            notificationListenerService = binder.getService()
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unbindService(connection, notificationListenerService)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        notificationListenerIntent = Intent(activity?.applicationContext, NLService::class.java)

        activity?.isServiceRunning(NLService::class.java)?.let { isServiceRunning ->
            if (isServiceRunning) {
                bindService(notificationListenerIntent, connection, 0)
            } else {
                logDebug("Service is not running!")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER -> startService(notificationListenerIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun stopService() {
        //BUG service doesn't seem to stop
        activity?.isServiceRunning(NLService::class.java)?.let { isServiceRunning ->
            if (isServiceRunning) {
                unbindService(connection, notificationListenerService)
                stopService(notificationListenerIntent)
            } else {
                logDebug("Service is not running!")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun startService() {
        activity?.isServiceRunning(NLService::class.java)?.let { isServiceRunning ->
            if (!isServiceRunning) {
                requestEnableNLService()
            } else {
                logDebug("Service is already running!")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun cancelAllNotifications() {
        notificationListenerService?.cancelAllNotifications()
    }

    private fun requestEnableNLService() {
        val intent = Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS")
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER)
    }
}
```

**Extension functions**

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")  // Deprecated for third party Services.
fun <T> Activity.isServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<T>): Boolean {
    return (getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
        .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .any { it.service.className == serviceClass.name }
}

fun Fragment.bindService(
    intent: Intent,
    connection: ServiceConnection,
    flags: Int
) {
    val isBind = activity?.applicationContext?.bindService(intent, connection, flags)
    logDebug("Service bind: $isBind.")
}


fun Fragment.unbindService(
    connection: ServiceConnection,
    notificationListenerService: NLService?
) {
    notificationListenerService?.isBound?.let {
        if (it) {
            activity?.applicationContext?.unbindService(connection)
            notificationListenerService.isBound = false
            logDebug("Service unbind.")
        }
    }
}

fun Fragment.startService(service: Intent) {
    activity?.applicationContext?.startService(service)
    logDebug("Service started")
}

fun Fragment.stopService(service: Intent) {
    val isStopped = activity?.applicationContext?.stopService(service)
    logDebug("Service stopped: $isStopped")
}
```

Comment: You cannot stop a notification listener service because it's bound by the system. Starting service manually is also pointless because in that case it won't be bound (by the system) and won't receive any notification callbacks nor it will be able to manipulate them.

Comment: What do you mean by manipulating them? I've managed to clear the notifications. I don't want to change the content of the notifications or alter them in some way. I'd like to store a copy of them, though.

Comment: You were able to manipulate them because you're not starting the service manually, it's created when system binds to it.

Comment: So my `NLService` is actually the `NotificationListenerService`? Can you please provide some related articles or tips? I don't really understand your point. Thank you

Comment: You have to use [`NotificationListenerService.requestRebind(ComponentName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#requestRebind(android.content.ComponentName)) instead of `context.startService` so system binds to it and grants you access to notificatoin manager. Starting this service by hand is pointless.